# Are questions about driving/traffic regulations on topic?

Tags: discussion

Travel.SE has quite a few questions about road rules ([example search](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=traffic%20light)), but many of them have been closed or have close-votes because they are "not about travel".

Are these kinds of questions on topic on Travel.SE?

Answer (score 4):

If the questions relate to travel, I'm good with them being asked and answered here.

Some of these questions could be:

- unique or unusual laws, restrictions, requirements etc.
- licensing requirements, and validity of foreign licenses in the jurisdiction
- insurance requirements, and validity of foreign insurance (particularly third-party liability insurance, which is often statutorily required)
- permits, fees, tolls - e.g. how to pay tolls in Oklahoma, USA; tell me about the road vignette required in Switzerland, etc.

I've asked a question on Travel.SE about US tolls, which I think was perfectly on the mark.  The traveler consideration for paying tolls is quite different than that of a permanent resident of a jurisdiction.

Comment: By "relate to travel" are you talking about questions a person who doesn't live in the area would ask? I mean, one could make the argument that driving is a form of traveling, and road rules are related to driving, so all questions about road rules automatically relate to travel, but I'm guessing that's not what you meant.

Comment: @DavidZ I suppose I meant that the question would relate to travel by people from outside that jurisdiction - things that wouldn't be obvious or would be helpful to know if you drove there yourself from home, or rented a car and drove there.

Answer (score 3):

**Depends.**

What is on-topic are questions about car travel, e.g.

- Is there anything I should need to know when traveling by car in country X (unusual signs and rules, confusing situations, right behavior in situations where normal knowledge is insufficient)?

I e.g. wrote some answers about German autobahn or traveling in Italy.

What we don't want here are answers about single situations which are much too special for an answer and are of very limited use for further users.

One of the closed question is asking if you should use the left or the right lane without markings when driving straight. This question could be right out of a driving license test and if a question resembles that, it is off-topic.